# i/o & console i/o difference

Tags: java, terminology

I am clear about i/o. But what is consle i/o? I googled but i am confused. Is that only for serialization or what is the sole purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically console I/O is for displaying output to the user and fetching input from the user. It can also be used (typically in Unix) to pipe data from one process to another.

It's typically *not* used with serialization.

Comment: with your fame I have some expectations. ;)  Maybe you should add the console I/O is also for text based interaction. Sometimes line-oriented, sometimes not. And maybe a link to an example: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jline/

Comment: @Amigable: Not *just* text-based though... it's a bit of a muddle, which complicates things. Some programs may expect binary input piped from another process, for example :( Of course, if you have your own suggestions for an answer, you could add your own :)